# How do you make it where when you react to a message it sends you a DM on discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So i am making a discord bot for a roleplay server on roblox and it has a ;host {link} command and it automatically gives itself a thumbs up reaction, how would I make it where if a user clicks this thumbs up it will DM them the link that you put while typing ;host

here is the current code,

```
@bot.command(aliases=["start"])
@commands.has_role(964936610489724998)
async def host(ctx, *, link=None):
    if link == None:
        await ctx.reply("**`Plase Include a link for your Private Server for users to be able to join`**")
    else:
        await ctx.message.delete()
        embed=discord.Embed(
            title="A user is Hosting an event",
            description=f"{ctx.author.mention} Is hosting a greenville server. Please react with the  emoji if you want to join! Remember to follow the rules while in the server. A direct message will soon be sent to you with the link to join.",
            color=0x0050ff
        )
    msg = await ctx.send("@everyone", embed=embed)
    await msg.add_reaction("")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `wait_for()`.

Insert the following code at the end of the function definition:

```py
def check(reaction, user):
    return str(reaction.emoji) == ''

try:
    reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    await channel.send('')  # Replace this with what you want to happen when there is a timeout
else:
    await channel.send('')  # Replace this with what you want to happen normally
```

[This code is modified from the discord.py docs.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to save config for this, for example by using [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) or [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html).

This is a basic pickle implementation that saves the message across bot restarts:

```py
def save_all():
    # PURELY FOR DEMONSTRATION. You should save this in an autosave function every x minutes, IO is precious
    # this saves the data into config.txt to be loaded in later
    with open('config.txt', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(client.config, f)
    print('saved')

@client.command(name='reaction')
async def reaction(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    msg = await ctx.send('this is a message to react to')
    await msg.add_reaction('\U0001f44d')
    client.config[msg.id] = {
        'reaction': '\U0001f44d',  # you can use custom emojis too
        'send': 'You reacted, so I will send this message to you'  # this is what you want to dm
    }
    save_all()

@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    message = reaction.message
    if message.id in client.config.keys() and reaction.emoji == client.config[message.id]['reaction']:
        await user.send(client.config[message.id]['send'])

with open('config.txt', 'rb') as f:
    client.config = pickle.load(f)
```